# Совпадение целой строки с помощью регулярного выражения

Tags: регулярные-выражения, javascript

Задача такая, что числа должны быть от 1 до 12, больше не может быть. Все числа должный быть отделены запятой, слов не может быть. 
Составил выражение `/([1-9]|1[0-2])$/`, но не знаю как ограничить числа от 1 до 12.

```
function Control ()
{
var str = document.getElementById("Field");
var re = /([1-9]|1[0-2])$/;
if (str != null)
  {
      if (str.search(re) != -1)
      {
      alert ("Корректные данные");
      }
         else
         { 
     alert ("Некоректные данные!");
          }
}
 else {}
}
```

Comment: Хм, приведите пример строки и того, что вы хотите получить в итоге, а то у вас в регулярке запятые не присутствуют, зато есть "конец строки".

Comment: var str = "1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12" - правильная строка
var str = "1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 9, 10" - правильная строка
var str = "1, 2, 13, 4, 5, 9, 10" - неправильная строка, есть число > 12
var str = "1, 2, текст, 4, 5, 9, 10" - неправильная строка, содержит слово

Comment: @Ion: вопрос на засыпку: что возвращает функция document.getElementById()?

Comment: @ZhukovRoman, я знаю! она возвращает html элемент :-)

Answer (score 1):

Исходя из Вашего комментария, могу сказать что тут не регулярка нужна.

Вот код

```
var s = "1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 9, 10, srt"
var arr = s.split(",");
var result = true;
for(var i in arr) {
    var num = parseInt(arr[i]) || 0;
    console.log(num);
    if (num < 1 || num > 12){
        result = false;
    }
}

if (result) {
    alert("true");
}else {
    alert("false")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Регулярное выражение `/([1-9]|1[0-2])$/` находит цифру от `1` до `9` или `10`, `11` или `12` *только в конце строки*.

**Если необходимо, чтобы регулярное выражение находило совпадение только ЦЕЛОЙ строки, заключите регулярки в `^` (*начало строки*) и `$` (*конец строки*)**:

```
/^([1-9]|1[0-2])$/
```

Любое регулярное выражение можно заставить вести себя таким образом, только нужно следить, чтобы альтернативные ветви были правильно сгруппированы. Если вы не уверены, используйте следующий подход:

```
/РЕГУЛЯРКА/ -> /^(?:РЕГУЛЯРКА ДЛЯ ЦЕЛОЙ СТРОКИ)$/
```

См. [демо онлайн](https://regex101.com/r/fHDqqH/2)

**Подобности**

- `^` - начало строки
- `(` - начало захватываемой группы (подмаски) (можно сделать её незахватываемой, добавив `?:` после `(` - `(?:` для оптимизации работы движка), которая содержит две альтернативы:

  - `[1-9]` - цифра от `1` до `9`
  - `|` - или
  - `1[0-2]` - цифра 1, за которой следует цифра от 0 до 2
- `)` - конец группы
- `$` - конец строки.