# Правильное условие для RegExp. (vk чат бот)

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения, node.js, vkontakte-api

Пишу чат бота для вк. Библиотека - [node-vk-bot-api](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-vk-bot-api)

Есть проблема, например у бота есть "команда", или он "слушает" определенное слово:

```
bot.event(/^(помощь)/i, function(ctx) {
 блаблабла
})
```

Из регулярки следует - что важно, чтобы слово "помощь" было первым и не имеет значения регистр. 
Но если у меня есть другая команда "помощь 2", то она игнорируется, т.к. бот уже
нацелен на функцию выше.

Пробовал сделать через

```
 bot.command(/^(помощь)/i, function(ctx) {
     блаблабла
    })
bot.command(/^(помощь 2)/i, function(ctx) {
     блаблабла
    })
```

результат аналогичен

Вопрос: Можно ли в регулярном выражении задать такой параметр, чтобы метод реагировал только в том случае, если это вообще единственное слово в строке?

Думал над вариантом, что если бот находит слово помощь, то дальше определяет есть ли в строке дополнительные слова которые могут перенаправить на другую функцию. Но решил что метод грязноват.
Есть ли другие способы это обойти?
Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Регулярное выражение (числа из диапазона 1-12)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/294293/%d0%a0%d0%b5%d0%b3%d1%83%d0%bb%d1%8f%d1%80%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b0-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d0%b4%d0%b8%d0%b0%d0%bf%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b0-1-12)

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте со знаком конца строки: `/^(помощь)$/i`

Comment: Помогло! Спасибо