# Как правильно оформить регулярное выражение?

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

regexp не конвертируется в строку(

```
function checkValidEmail(email) {
    let regexp = /\A[^@]+@([^@\.]+\.)+[^@\.]+\z/;
    return email.match(regexp);
}
```

Comment: Так match и не должен конвертировать.

Comment: @AlexanderLonberg почему возвращает null всегда?

Comment: Потому что спереди и сзади стоят непонятные литералы "А и z". Если их убрать, то будет возвращать массив совпадений для любого валидного адреса. Но только имя домена, потому как круглые скобки только там.

Comment: Кстати там нет начала и конца выражения `/^xxx$/`, так что это поймает адрес в любой строке.

Comment: @AlexanderLonberg как тогда правильно? let regexp = /^\A[^@]+@([^@\.]+\.)+[^@\.]+\z$/;

Comment: `/^[^@]+@(?:[^@\.]+\.)+[^@\.]+$/`

Comment: Надо привести пример любого адреса, который должен совпасть и указать что нужно на выходе, а то не ясно - просто строка или какой либо элемент из регулярки - например только имя юзера

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Совпадение целой строки с помощью регулярного выражения](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/294293/%d0%a1%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%bf%d0%b0%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%86%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b9-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d1%81-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%be%d1%89%d1%8c%d1%8e-%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b3%d1%83%d0%bb%d1%8f%d1%80%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
let pattern = /^[^@]+@(?:[^@\.]+\.)+[^@\.]+$/;

console.log('some@some.some'.match(pattern));
console.log('cheating@some'.match(pattern));
console.log('@cheating.some'.match(pattern));
console.log('cheating.some'.match(pattern));
```