# Проверка ввода положительных целых чисел и чисел с плавающей точкой или запятой

Tags: javascript, jquery, регулярные-выражения

Подскажите, что то у меня не работает данное регулярное выражение... Мне нужно осуществить проверку на введение положительных целочисленных чисел и чисел с плавающей точкой или плавающей запятой.
Вот я написал следующий код, но он срабатывает некорректно... Точно такое же выражение работает на регулярках с++ и кьют... Здесь почему то не пашет... ? В чем может быть причина?

Вот пример заведомо некорректных вводов, которые он легко пропускает(перечисление через точку с запятой): 12..32;  1,2.34..4; 344,3,3 и т.д.
Не пропускает только ввод с символами на борту...

```
let regAnswer = new RegExp("[0-9]+[\.,]{0,1}[0-9]*");
if(regAnswer.test($(".arbOnlineSheet .NoInput_On").val())){
    alert("Good");
}
```

Comment: начало и конец вставьте `^[0-9]+[\.,]{0,1}[0-9]*$`

Comment: а при чем тут символ "^" ?  В любом случае не работает...

Comment: @Alexander Lonberg, нашел в интернете примеры с регулярками /^   и $/, но эффект также пока отсутствует... Подразумеваю, что фигурные скобки он не может интерпретировать...

Comment: @Alexander Lonberg, Спасибо, помогло=))

Comment: В вашем случае указатель на повторения `{0,1}` легко заменяется вопросительным знаком `?`. Суть та же

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Совпадение целой строки с помощью регулярного выражения](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/294293/%d0%a1%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%bf%d0%b0%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%86%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b9-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d1%81-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%be%d1%89%d1%8c%d1%8e-%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b3%d1%83%d0%bb%d1%8f%d1%80%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f)

Answer (score 1):

Можно сделать проверку через конвертацию в числовой формат с помощью `Number`, который в случае некорректного числа вернет `NaN`

```
let str = $(".arbOnlineSheet .NoInput_On").val();
let number = Number(str.replace(/,/, '.')); 
if (!isNaN(number) && number >= 0) { // если число и число положительное  
   alert("Good");
}
```

второй вариант - через регулярное выражение

```
let regAnswer = new RegExp("^[+]?([0-9]*[.,])?[0-9]+$");
if(regAnswer.test($(".arbOnlineSheet .NoInput_On").val().trim())){
    alert("Good");
}
```